# What is the usage of comment notations in style tag?

Tags: html, css

For example :

```
<style type="text/css">
    <!--
    #map{ width:500px;height:500px;float:left }
    -->
</style>
```

What is the usage of `<!-- -->` ?

Comment: Fun fact: Microsoft Word 2013's "Save As Webpage" option still generates markup like the above, which is how I found my way here.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It stops Netscape 2 era browsers, which don't recognize the `<style>` element, from rendering the content as text (since they start to render the content, but it is a comment, so it isn't rendered).

This is described in [the HTML specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/styles.html#h-14.5).

Entirely worthless today, but people keep adding them without understanding them in a cargo cult mentality.

Answer (score -2):

I only use that type of comment  for mock up when I want to remember my reasoning behind a certain structure of elements or have something I want to remember to add later. I never use those comments in production webpages.