# Why is there often a <!-- inside the style tag?

Tags: html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the usage of comment notations in style tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4447531/what-is-the-usage-of-comment-notations-in-style-tag)

I was wondering that often when writing css code inside a html document there is `<!--` just behind the style tag. So for example: `<style type="text/css"><!--
body { text-align: center; } --></style>`

In my knowledge this is a html comment but why is it put inside the style tag, whats the sense? Is it to exclude certain browsers which will see it as a comment?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It is an HTML comment ensuring a browser will not interpret the CSS within the `style` element as HTML to display.

Mostly used for (very) old browsers that did not support CSS at all or did not know it ignore the content within the element.

This was also commonly done with inline javascript.

Comment: As a point of reference, keep in mind that it was no longer needed for browsers contemporary with Netscape 4.x (around 2000). **It's completely unnecessary today.**

Comment: Small nit: [inline styles](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/present/styles.html#h-14.2.2) are something like `<p style="color: red;">` what the OP is asking about is a [`<style>` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/present/styles.html#h-14.2.3)

Answer (score 1):

"Is it to exclude certain browsers which will see it as a comment?"

Yes.

Answer (score 0):

This is to avoid the browser from interpreting the CSS code as HTML.

Comment: It's worth noting that a browser that *does* understand CSS won't make this mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Back in the day, not every browser supported the style tag. Offending browsers would output the contents of the tag to the page. The comment tags prevent these old browsers from writing the tag content to the page. This hasn't been needed for about 10 years.